# How can I convert from a C-style WCHAR* to a Rust string?

Tags: winapi, rust

I want to print the `lfFaceName` field of the `LOGFONTW` struct using `println!`.

How can I convert this C-style `WCHAR*` to a `Vec<u16>` and to a Rust string. There are answers for simpler questions using `*const u8`, but I have a `*const u16`.

Comment: @Boiethios, winapi-rs is a thin wrapper over windows API. It doesn't provide function for converting zero-terminated UTF-16 strings into Rust's `String`

Comment: Problematic are 16-bit C-style strings

Comment: `#[cfg(windows)]
    fn from_wide_string(s: &[u16]) -> String {
        use std::ffi::OsString;
        use std::os::windows::ffi::OsStringExt;
        let slice = s.split(|&v| v == 0).next().unwrap();
        OsString::from_wide(slice).to_string_lossy().into()
    }`

Comment: let str = String::from_utf16_lossy(font_struct.lfFaceName) - is near ok, but expected type `&[u16]`  found type `[u16; 32]`- problem is that it is not pointer but 32 word array

Comment: Then you don't have a `WCHAR*`, you have a `[WCHAR; 32]`. Either way, just get a slice `let str = String::from_utf16_lossy(font_struct.lfFaceName.as_slice())`.

Comment: I add: let face_name_ptr = &mut font_struct.lfFaceName as &[u16];

Comment: `String::from_utf16_lossy` [doesn't work as expected for zero-terminated strings](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b9d606a23ad4ec9d6fda562ff5b30d4f&version=stable)

Comment: Problem solved: two stages: 1)let face_name_ptr = &mut font_struct.lfFaceName as &[u16]; 2)red75prime's method

Comment: @Bor, `String::from_utf16_lossy(&font_struct.lfFaceName)` will work, except for including all symbols past first 0.

Comment: @red75prime I always hesitate when to introduce people to that. It's not obvious to newcomers how `Deref` coercions work and often makes things more confusing. However, `&font_struct.lfFaceName` is far more idiomatic.

Comment: @red75prime It depends on what you "expect" for UTF-16 ^_^. UTF-16 is allowed to have embedded NUL characters, therefore **I** expect that behavior.

Comment: @Shepmaster, in the context of this question the string is zero-terminated UTF-16 as per [LOGFONTW documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741231(v=vs.85).aspx). Garbage after font name will be unexpected, I think.